# Randomness test suites that can be invoked from Mathematica

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, interoperability

There are several test suites referenced at [csrc.nist.gov](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/batteries_stats_test.html) designed to test a (pseudo-)random byte sequence for randomness, and discover possible skews, correlations, patterns, or other hidden non-randomness in it.

Are there implementations of any of them or other similar test suites in *Mathematica*? Or some precompiled libraries (including *Java* or *.NET* modules) that can be invoked from *Mathematica* running on *Windows*?

Comment: Perhaps this: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5718/  It's a bit old, but I don't have time to check it out.  (Sorry.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know there are no test suites that can be invoked directly from *Mathematica*. One can of course use the traditional ones such as the one you mention or the NIST or the Marsaglia's diehard tests. I implemented some "toy tests" in [this Wolfram Demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RandomNumberGeneration/) to illustrate Mathematica's various built-in PRNGs, which fail or succeed the toy tests depending on various factors.
There is also [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1109.5282) that implemented the NIST tests in *Mathematica*.
It is written in Spanish though, although the abstract is in English. Its content is in the context of Elementary Cellular Automata.

Answer (score 2):

This page has a download link for Ilja Gerhardt's updated version of Galbreath's notebook: https://gerhardt.ch/random.php